# What is the most optimized/shortest JSON structure I can use to submit multiple records to SOLR

Tags: java, json, solr

Is this JSON legal to add documents to SOLR?

```
{
 "add": [{"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"}}]
}
```

I am using SOLR 3.4 and submit using CURL from inside PHP.
What should I see in the logs if this is not correct?

**EDIT**:This question was mistakenly understood as if I have a bug in the structure above (I did have a missing bracket) That was not the purpose. The question is a more generalized one, I edited the title to reflect this.

Comment: your last object in the array is missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `}` at the end there, are you not?

```
{
"add": [{"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
        {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} },
        {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
        {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} }]
}
```

Comment: yes, but the question is about the general structure not if I have a missing bracket. I fixed the question though - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this site:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

No, it is not valid JSON.

Here it is, cleaned up for you:

```
{
 "add": [
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
         {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
"add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
"add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"} },
"add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"} },
"add": {"doc": {"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"}}
}'
```

OR

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
{"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"},
{"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"},
{"id" : "TestDoc1", "title" : "test1"},
{"id" : "TestDoc2", "title" : "another test"}
]'
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is the best (and shortest) JSON structure from within PHP. Would I need to use all those "add" or is it enough to have just one?

Comment: The second option mentioned by me is the shortest is its all adds. For mentioning all adds, depends on which Solr version you are using 3.1 needs all adds. However, the newer ones allow you to use nested objects @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

Comment: I am familiar with the Wiki you gave here, it gives examples up to 3.1 But, I understand from your response my example is good. Thanks!